# Blender models issues when importing into Substance Painter

Tags: mesh, export

Hello I'm new to Blender and SP, please go easy on me.

I've created a model in Blender, when importing features that have been boolean'd with difference modifier from blender to SP, I get mesh distortion in SP and allot of errors. I have tried applying before exporting as well.

> [Scene 3D] Failed to triangulate polygon (no ear found). Probably not
> a simple polygon?

I gather this is a blender setup issue. Here is an example of the blender Model:
[image]
And the SP import of the model.
[image]

Here is the pre-export blender mesh:
[image]

Thank you in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it, found out the issues. Substance Painter does not like faces with more than 4 nodes. Correcting that fixed it up straight away.